# Laravel: How to load an HTML page with Morris chart as PDF using thujohn/pdf-l4 plugin?

Tags: html, laravel-4, wkhtmltopdf, dompdf, export-to-pdf

I am using Larvel 4.2 and thujohn/pdf-l4 plugin.

I have a problem in converting an HTML page to PDF. When I convert an HTML page, Everything on the page are displayed except the Morris chart on it.

My Route

```
Route::post('performanceDetail/preview',[
    'as' => 'print.preview',
    'uses' => 'PerformanceController@postPerformanceDetails']);
```

Controller

```
public function postPerformanceDetails()
{
    $data = [
        'event' => Input::get('events'),
        'start_date' => Input::get('start_date'),
        'to_date' => Input::get('to_date'),
    ];
        $start_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($data['start_date'].'00:00:00'));
        $to_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime($data['to_date'].'23:59:59'));
        $stats = Performance::where('event_type','=',$data['event'])
        ->where('campaign_id',Session::get('campaignid'))
        ->where('created_at', '>=',$start_date)
        ->where('created_at','<=',$to_date)
        ->groupBy('perf_date')
        ->orderBy('perf_date', 'DESC')
        ->remember(60)
        ->get([
        DB::raw('Date(created_at) as perf_date'),
        DB::raw('COUNT(id) as perf_count')
        ])
        ->toJSON();
        //return $stats;
        $campaign = Campaign::find(Session::get('campaignid'));
        $list = CategoryList::find($campaign->categorylist_id);
        $totalPerformance = TotalPerformance::find(Session::get('totalPerformance'));
        //$this->layout->title = "Performance details";
        return PDF::load(View::make('performance.show')
        ->with('stats',$stats)
        ->with('campaign',$campaign)
        ->with('list',$list)
        ->with('start_date',$data['start_date'])
        ->with('to_date',$data['to_date'])
        ->with('totalPerformance',$totalPerformance))->show();
}
```

View

```html
{{-- Form to view performance details --}}
<html lang="en">
    <head>
  <p align="center">
   <b> <font size="5" >Performance report</font></b>
  </p>
 </head>
 <body>
  <p align="center"> 
   <font size="4" >{{{$campaign->template->title}}}</font></b>
  </p>
  <p>
    <b>List:&nbsp;</b><font>{{$list->name}} </font>
  </p>
  <br>
  <p>
   <b>Total performance</b>
  </p>
  <p>
   <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="100">Campaign</th>
            <th width="50" >Sent</th>
            <th width="50" >Clicks</th>
            <th width="50" >Loads</th>
            <th width="50" >Opens</th>
            <th width="50" >Views</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td align="center" width="200">{{{$campaign->template->title}}}</td>
         <td align="center" width="50">{{$totalPerformance->totalSent }}</td>
         <td width="50" align="center">{{$totalPerformance->clicks }}</td>
         <td width="50" align="center">{{$totalPerformance->loads }}</td>
         <td width="50" align="center">{{$totalPerformance->opens }}</td>
         <td width="50" align="center">{{$totalPerformance->views }}</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
  </p>
  <br>
  <p>
   <b>Date</b>
  </p>
  <p>
   From: &nbsp;{{$start_date}} &nbsp;&nbsp; To: &nbsp; {{$to_date}}
  </p>
  {{-- hosted assets for Morris charts --}}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
  {{ HTML::script('../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js') }}
  {{ HTML::script('../bower_components/raphael/raphael-min.js') }}
  {{ HTML::script('../bower_components/morrisjs/morris.min.js') }}
  <input type="hidden" name="dataChart" id="dataChart" value="{{{$stats}}}">
  <div id="mchart">
   
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
   var events = $('#dataChart').val();
      console.log(events);

   var chart = Morris.Bar({
      barGap:1,
      barSizeRatio:.10,
      // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
      element: 'mchart',
      // Set initial data (ideally you would provide an array of default data)
      data: [0,0],
      xkey: 'perf_date',
      ykeys: ['perf_count'],
      labels: ['Count'],
      //barColors: ['#0B62A4','#f75b68','#4DA74D','#646464'],
      hideHover: 'auto'
      });
   chart.setData(JSON.parse(events));
      
   
  });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I have tried to display this view without conversion, it was successful. But, when executed the above code the Morris Chart is not displayed on PDF.

How can I solve this Please guide.

Comment: Looks like the chart is JS-based, which dompdf does not handle. You'll have to go with another package (wkhtmltopdf or PhantomJS).

Answer (score 0):

Just use the {!! !!} instead of using {{ }} in your view file...

Also make sure that your file should be something like 
'demo.blade.php'..